# iMessage App - Using a UITextField in compact presentation style

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit

I'm simply trying to use a `UITextField` for my iMessage App.

The problem is with when it is in compact mode (`MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact`) once you select the textfield, all the views disappear. It seems to work fine in expanded mode.

What is the proper way of using a textfield in compact mode? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you can only use textfields while in expanded mode, so you'll need to implement something like this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if([self presentationStyle] == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact) {
        [self requestPresentationStyle:MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded];
        self.didRequestKeyboard = YES;
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)didTransitionToPresentationStyle:(MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle)presentationStyle {
    // Called after the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

    // Use this method to finalize any behaviors associated with the change in presentation style.
    if(presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded){
        if(self.didRequestKeyboard){
            [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
            self.didRequestKeyboard = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error at line  self.didRequestKeyboard = YES;

I have added a UITextFieldDelegate in MSMessagesAppViewController class.

Comment: @Vin this variable is implemented in your own class

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem (still present as of iOS 10.2) and ended on this workaround:

```
fileprivate class TextField: UITextField {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        if let viewController = viewController as? MSMessagesAppViewController,
           viewController.presentationStyle == .compact {
            viewController.requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)
            return false
        }
        return super.canBecomeFirstResponder
    }
}
```

I say "workaround" because I feel this is a problem Apple should solve ergo this solution should be temporary. This implementation, as an alternative to the original answer's, is segregated and can be easily ripped out.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution but using blocks

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if presentationStyle != .expanded {
        didTransitionHandler = {
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            self.didTransitionHandler = nil
        }

        requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```